# Expired memberships being erased by new memberships using Webform

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

we have a problem with expired members renewing.

When they renew using our webform, the old membership is replaced completely with the new membership. This means we lose the key 'member since' data.

They also show as a new member and not a current member which presents problems for us.

This does not happen when someone is in the grace period.
This does not happen if we manually renew the expired membership.

We use webform civicrm intergration with paypal standard. Drupal 7. Latest version of webforms and civicrm intergration. CIVICRM 4.5.8.

Any help resolving this issue would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: I changed title and added tag to reflect more clearly this is Webform rather than a standard civi Contribution page as it may have implications for the answers.

Comment: Also I see you are saying Expired member. The behaviour for Expired is different to Grace and there has been a lot of discussion eg https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/renewing-expired-membership about how to better handle the different approaches users of civi need from this.

Comment: Also, it may help if you can edit your question to make it crystal clear whether the behaviour you describe is only for Expired or if it affects Grace members too.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to check out how to send existing members a renewal link via CiviMail. Webform CiviCRM provides you a handy link on the CiviCRM tab and an explanation.

The key concept here is that you can send contacts a special/unique-to-them link to the renewal page that bakes in their existing contact id so that the page already knows them and their membership, making the renewal easier for them and for CiviCRM.

Comment: No that's not the issue. As we have tried that also and again the current membership is wiped out and completely replaced.

Comment: Sounds like you're in the dark bowels of the membership module. I can confirm that the method I've described does work on a 4.6 CiviCRM + Drupal 7 installation, so I'd recommend you upgrade your Civi if you possibly can.

Answer (score 1):

A CiviCRM contact should only have one membership record for membership in a given organization (when you created the membership types, you associated the membership with an organization contact). If someone renews an expired membership, it won't create an additional membership record, it will update the expiration date of the existing membership. You can keep track of this with the Member Since and Membership Start dates.

The Member Since field is the date the contact first joined (ever). The Membership Start is the date of the most recent *continuous* membership period.

So, if a member joins with a rolling 1 year membership period on 1/1/2012 and expires on 12/31/2012, and lets his/her membership lapse, then rejoins on 6/15/2014 and stays in good standing, the membership record should show

- Member Since: 1/1/2012
- Membership Start: 6/15/2014
- Membership End: 6/14/2017

assuming they renewed in 2015 and 2016 before the membership ended or during the grace period.

Comment: Dan - I think this is a good answer for standard civi behaviour. am not sure how much it adds to the scenario under discussion where it seems like it is the webform-civicrm integration that is triggering the unexpected behaviour - but maybe i am not reading between the lines and you could perhaps clarify further in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is an issue with the webform_civicrm code. Have raised [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2852365)